# Can I display an Ipython notebook hosted on bitbucket?

Tags: ipython, bitbucket

I have a very simple notebook, hosted on github and on bitbucket.
The [github URL](https://github.com/thomas-haslwanter/statsintro/blob/master/ipynb/demo.ipynb)
displays fine in the [nbviewer](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/), but the [bitbucket URL](https://bitbucket.org/thomas_haslwanter/mypython/src/feeac36234b52c0573c4838df428a299c04e6969/CSS/ipynb/demo.ipynb?at=master)
- which should indicate the same trivial notebook - does not work with the nbviewer.

Is it possible that nbviewer only takes github notebooks?

Later comment:
my repo was private - so that was at least one reason why it could not work!

Comment: I get a `404` error when I click on your bitbucket link.

Comment: nbviewer does work with any URL, though you may need to give it the 'raw' URL from Bitbucket, rather than the URL of the page displaying that file - nbviewer can recognise Github file display URLs and fetch the raw file instead, but I don't think it does that for Bitbucket. And it won't work if your repo is private.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is/was the first result when googling for this, I just thought I'd update and let everyone know that this is now an add-on available in Bitbucket. You can find it under Settings -> Find Integrations. The source and issue tracker are available here - https://bitbucket.org/bitbucket/bitbucket-nbviewer

Comment: How to make it default view for .ipynb?

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [issue](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/11318/enable-rich-rendering-of-jupyter-notebooks) on Bitbucket's issue tracker, it does not seem to be supported yet.

Comment: Can you link to the bitbucket issue tracker issue?

Comment: My bad. Was working at night with flux on my monitor so the link text appeared the same color as the text

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @ThomasK in the comments, you can display a notebook from bitbucket if you copy the raw address.

Just click on the three dots next to your notebook and copy the address that you get when you click on **Open raw**.

[image]

Copy this address...

[image]

... and paste it in the text box in https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/ ...

[image]

... and it will render your notebook:

[image]