# Rendering Jupiter notebooks in Bitbucket privately under Git?

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook

I need Notebooks to be hosted and rendered somewhere. Possible in Bitbucket?

Answer (score 3):

I know it's late but they do support this feature in late October now. See [this link](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/11318/enable-rich-rendering-of-jupyter-notebooks) for reference. Basically, you can use the addon/integration and change preview of `ipynb` files.

Comment: Good one! There is yet a crucial bug found: https://bitbucket.org/bitbucket/bitbucket-nbviewer/issues/2/addon-not-working-on-private-repo

Comment: @hhh, Weird - my repos are private yet I can use the addon w/o any problem.

Answer (score 2):

Atlassian and Bitbucket do not support rich rendering of Jupyter notebooks. So we must look at third-party alternatives such as Nbviewer.jupyter.org, requiring a public url. Because Chrome extensions rely on the public urls, the rendering cannot be done for private repos, not in bitbucket or other service.

**Related**

- Open issue in Bitbucket about rich rendering like in Github [here](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/11318/enable-rich-rendering-of-jupyter-notebooks)
- Nbviewer.jupyter.org and its chromebook extension do not work with private notebooks, [Can I display an Ipython notebook hosted on bitbucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053206/can-i-display-an-ipython-notebook-hosted-on-bitbucket)
- [What are proper ways to integrate Jupyter Notebooks in Atlassian Stack such as Confluence and Bitbucket](https://www.quora.com/What-are-proper-ways-to-integrate-Jupyter-Notebooks-in-Atlassian-Stacks-such-as-Confluence-and-Bitbucket)

**Other**

- Github is able to do the Jupyter notebook rendering according to this [here](https://github.com/blog/1995-github-jupyter-notebooks-3)

  - Examples [here](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/A-gallery-of-interesting-Jupyter-Notebooks#statistics-machine-learning-and-data-science)
- Gitlab is able to do the Jupyter notebook rendering according to [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/2508)
- Client side rendering of Jupyter notebooks [here](https://github.com/kokes/nbviewer.js)